# Tacoma Narrows bridge collapse : mathematical explanation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, math-history, applications

What is the exact mathematical reason behind the [Tacoma narrow bridge collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacoma_Narrows_Bridge_(1940)) ?
I have googled about the collapse , but I didn't get a correct reason and a mathematical model.

Comment: Please provide all the necessary details about this `Tacoma narrow bridge collision` event instead of sending us to look it up on Google.

Comment: @daniel, see the answers, and Wikipedia.  The standard account seems to have been wrong and for a long time.

Comment: @barakmanos, it is a famous case discussed in many introductory physics books to illustrate resonant frequency.  The illustration may have been misleading, it is an interesting and essentially mathematical problem to analyze the problem accurately.

Comment: @zyx: I still that think it's reasonable to ask the OP to provide more details (in particularly, those that are necessary in order to answer the question).

Comment: @zyx: Of course that is precisely what I learned in my physics text some years ago. I will update my software accordingly, thanks!

Comment: In some languages the term for a bridge collapse would be the same as a bridge "crash", which can translates to English as "collision" (as in car crash).  @JoelReyesNoche

Comment: The question concerns unsteady Aerodynamics, Flutter, oscillations on the  " galloping Gertie", Even today is a red area of ignorance. At the time it was built the bridge conformed to state of art. Several bridges including Golden Gate CA were strengthened in hindsight. The flimsy ribbon deck was destroyed in shear twisting by the vortices. A good reference is https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/McKenna1-18.pdf  The topic should be neither down voted nor closed

Comment: The link is the McKenna 1999 paper (see answer).   @Narasimham

Comment: @barakmanos, which details are necessary to answer the question?  The bridge collapse is a very well known event, and anyone who could possibly answer the question will immediately recognize it.  Four people *did* answer it (two comments, two answers).

Comment: @zyx: And five people closed it for missing context or details.

Comment: @barakmanos, only one of the first 4 votes was "missing context", apparently yours.  At 5 votes it is not possible to check the reasons, and the listed reason is "not about mathematics", not "missing context or details".  So: exactly what details are missing to answer the question?  There are 4 answers so far that seemed to consider it detailed enough.

Comment: @zyx: "not about mathematics" is even worse than "missing context or details" (which can at least be fixed) IMO.

Comment: Note that McKenna, Gustafson and Moore (cited in answer) are mathematics professors employed in university mathematics departments, and the papers available at those links were published in mathematics journals.  If only those professors had the wisdom of math.stackexchange voters available to them, they would have known that the question of what caused the bridge to collapse is "not about mathematics".  Saves a lot of research time!     @barakmanos

Comment: @zyx: What I generally meant to say (in my original comment) was that the OP should post all the relevant details instead of assuming that they are some sort of common knowledge. I often write the same type of comments, for example, on Poker or Bridge questions which do not specify the relevant details (and I'm pretty sure that the latter are "a lot more common knowledge" than this incident).

Answer (score 1):

The old physics textbook explanation in terms of 'resonant frequency' is disputed by closer analysis and simulation.   In addition to the extensive discussion at Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacoma_Narrows_Bridge_(1940)#Cause_of_the_collapse

there are some articles by P.J. McKenna challenging the (then) standard account as due to incorrect approximation of the equations:

https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/McKenna1-18.pdf

http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/tnarrows/

Kristen Moore (McKenna's PhD student at the time he wrote his article) has several publications on this subject at her webpage

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ksmoore/publist.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the failure of the Tacoma bridge in 1940.

It is difficult to provide a detailed reply here (and IANAExpert), but this was a classic case of [aeroelastic flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroelasticity#Flutter), a harmful and self-reinforcing interaction between a structure and a fluid. Structural dynamicists study such problems.

Comment: The page on flutter cites the 1991 article by Billah and Scanlan as the reference for that as the cause of the Tacoma Narrows collapse, but it is not clear to me if their analysis is compatible with the later one by McKenna (1999) that attempted to model the bridge cables more realistically.